# Make Fixed Gridview Header to ignore browser Scroll-bar JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridview

Is there a way to have the fixed header only to respond to only one scroll bar in JQuery? In this case to respond only to the div scroll bar and not the browser scroll bar. Or is there a different solution. I tried getting rid of the browser scroll bar but then all the gridview contend wont be accessible.

Background:
I have a JQuery cloned gridview header which is inside of a div with scrolling bars, this is the code:

```
    function fixedHeader() {
        // Code to copy the gridview header with style
        var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true).attr('id','clonedGrid'); 
        //Code to remove all rows except the header row
        $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
            // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table th 
            $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
        });
        // Append Header to the div controlHead
        $("#controlHead").append(gridHeader);
        // Set its position to be fixed
        $('#controlHead').css('position', 'fixed');
        // Put it on top
        $('#controlHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);
    }
```

It works perfect when the window is maximized but when I re-size the browser and the browser scroll bar appears, the header will obey both scroll bars (the one from the div and the one from the browser) making the header to move as well when I scroll with the browser scroll bar thus making the fixed header off like what you see below![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTMkP.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I modified my JQuery code to change it to absolute, and add a z index, along with setting the height of each th from the grid into the new cloned table 
This is how the code looks like and works 100%

```
    function fixedHeader() {
        // Code to copy the gridview header with style
        var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true).attr('id','clonedGrid'); 
        //Code to remove all rows except the header row
        $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
            // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table th 
            $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
            // Here Set height of each th from gridview to new table th 
            $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('height', ($(this).height()).toString() + "px");
        });
        // Append Header to the div controlHead
        $("#controlHead").append(gridHeader);
        // Set its position to be fixed
        $('#controlHead').css('position', 'absolute');
        // Bring the header in front of everything else
        $('#controlHead').css('z-index', '200');
        // Put it on top
        $('#controlHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);
    }
```